# Parse PHP in HTML files - files download instead of parse

Tags: php, hosting, .htaccess, html

Seems easy, right?  Done it a million times, right?  Me too.  For some reason this isn't working on an A2 hosting configuration.  Anyone have any ideas?

In .htaccess in "/" directory

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

test.php which is "Hello World" executes just fine.  test.html downloads instead of parsing.

I have read lots of Q&As and no luck.  What is missing?  What other configs can I examine?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using mod_php or CGI?  What does `phpinfo();` tell you for Server API?

Comment: @DerfK CGI/FastCGI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is legal or not but I am responding to my own question so the answer is there for others to use in the future.

For some reason the default file permissions were all set to 777 or 666 which caused issues with them being served correctly.  By adjusting the file permissions to 644, these issues were solved.  Of course the .htaccess AddType was also required.

Comment: It's 100% permitted, and encouraged if none of the other answers were appropriate. You can even give yourself the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Is the module loaded? E.g. `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: I added `<IfModule !php5_module>
  # If the PHP5 module has NOT already been loaded, load it
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>` but that creates a server error.  How else can I check if the module loaded?  .php files work so I assume that it works?

Comment: I misread your post. My answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

look if .htaccess is allowed to be read into the directory you have it.
into httpd.conf you will need to have AllowOverride for that location
see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: htaccess is allowed into that directory.  Thanks though.